# Screen rotation with viewpager, tablelayout and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I spend time to search an answer to my problem without success.

When i rotating my fragments are recreated inside viewpager adapter but not displayed, i don't no why ?

I have tried FragmentPagerStateAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter but it doesn't work.

My activity code :

```
public class BookingsActivity extends BaseActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,LoginDialogFragment.LoginDialogFragmentListener, BookingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    .....

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(BookingsFragment.newInstance(), "A venir");
    adapter.addFragment(BookingsFragment.newInstance(), "Terminées");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<BookingsFragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public BookingsFragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(BookingsFragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

My fragment code :

```
public class BookingsFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<Bookings> mBookings = new ArrayList<>();
private BookingCardAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Location mLastLocation;

public BookingsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static BookingsFragment newInstance() {
    BookingsFragment fragment = new BookingsFragment();
    // Supply index input as an argument.
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookings, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    adapter = new BookingCardAdapter(mBookings, this.getContext(), new BookingCardAdapter.BookingCardAdapterSubmitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBookingClick(Bookings booking, int state) {
            handleBookingClick(booking,state);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public void setBookings(ArrayList<Bookings> bookings, int page) {
    if (bookings != null && bookings.size() > 0) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            if (page == 1) {
                mBookings.clear();
            }
            for (Bookings b : bookings) {
                mBookings.add(b);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    if (location!=null) {
        mLastLocation=location;
    }

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: When you rotate screen fragment destroyed and recreated, if want to display same data then use OnsaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstance method in your fragments.